# Nested dereference of delay

Tags: clojure, delay

```
@(delay (delay 1)) ; equals to unrealized delay object, containing 1.
```

Is there an easy *(without a head-first macross which tests each block with `realized?`)* way to deref all inner delays recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arthur's code certainly works for the example you've posted, but here is an example of how you could handle mixed sequences:

```
(defn deref-delays [x]
  (cond
    (sequential? x) (map deref-delays x)
    (= clojure.lang.Delay (class x)) (recur @x)
    :else x))

(deref-delays [1 2 (delay 3) (delay [4 (delay (delay 5)) 6]) 7])
;(1 2 3 (4 5 6) 7)
```

Comment: cool code :-) `(or (sequential? x) (map? x))` make it "work" with maps (they are not maps afterwords though :-/

Comment: I'd probably replace `(= clojure.lang.Delay (class x))` with `(instance? clojure.lang.Delay x)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that if there where many nested delays, you want a function to retrieve the value from the inner most delay?

```
(defn recursive-deref [delays] 
  (if (= clojure.lang.Delay (type delays)) 
    (recur @delays) 
    delays))
#'user/recursive-deref
user> (recursive-deref delays)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use clojure.walk to do this and preserve structure.

```
(defn deref-walk [x] 
  (clojure.walk/prewalk 
    (fn [e] 
      (if (delay? e) 
        (deref-walk (deref e)) 
        e)) 
    x))
```

Then

```
(deref-walk (delay {:a 1 :b (delay [1 2 (delay 3) (delay {:c 4})])}))
```

Results in

```
{:a 1 :b [1 2 3 {:c 4}]}
```